# Inserting new data into an existing table

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I had a table created, then I added a new column to it. I need to insert new data next to the existing data.

I tried to make id and value related. To add a new value with a different ID

```
id_apartment = [row[0] for row in cursorObj.execute('select link_id from apartments').fetchall()] # I get the id of each row of an already existing table
for i in id_apartment:
    for k in mass:
        print(k)
        cursorObj.execute(f'update apartments set lon = {k[0]} where id_apartment={i}')
        con.commit()
```

In this case the error: OperationalError: unrecognized token: ":"

Here's another one

```
for i in mass:
    cursorObj.execute(f'update apartments set lon = {i[0]}')
    con.commit()
```

But then it takes the value and inserts it into all rows

I need to add 2 columns: lat and lon. Their values are stored in an array.

Comment: Don't substitute values into the SQL string, use a prepared statement with parameters.

Comment: @AliasCartellano He's not adding new rows, he's filling in data in a new column.

Comment: Why are you updating the same row multiple times in your loop?

Comment: How do you know which value in `mass` should be put into which row of the table?

Comment: @AliasCartellano Where? I don't see any use of `UPDATE` queries there.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use nested loops. To put one element of `mass` in each row, loop over the two lists in parallel with `zip()`.

```
for i, k in zip(id_apartment, mass):
    cursorObj.execute('update apartments set lon = ? where id_apartment=?', (k[0], i))
```